# Which Programming Language have a best image filter?

Tags: opencv, photo, imagick, image-effects

Which programming language has best possible image filter and also provide art photo effect and oil paint effect. I've also tried in php-imagick, python-opencv, css, and javascript but they do not exactly provide art effect and oil paint effect.

Prisma app also provide art and oil paint effect but they use neural network and ai technology so how can I use this both technology for my project.

Comment: the gimp is open source and probably has that kind of filters, so you could use tha language innehich gimp is written?!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have mentioned `php-imagick` and `python-opencv`, what you need is a library that provides you the tools you want, the programming language is irrelevant.

Have a look at [G'MIC](http://gmic.eu/) and the [image gallery](http://gmic.eu/gallery.shtml).

Comment: Yes.!! G'MIC is very cool but i need a program. so how can i use GMIC in my project ??

Comment: @Chirag_php See [libgmic](http://gmic.eu/libgmic.shtml) or [gmic-community](https://github.com/dtschump/gmic-community).